# MVC dropdown list will not display stored value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've looked through many posts and a few examples on ways to create a dropdown list in MVC and Razor with not much like figuring out my issue.

Basically I have this line of code that creates my dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MarketSegmentID,
                               new SelectList(""),
                               new { @class = "dropdownList"})
```

Then with JQuery I fill in the dropdown with values from the controller

Then I post my form and the selected value in the dropdown comes over correctly.

The issue I am running into is when I open the form back up I cant get my saved value from the model to show as the selected value.

For fun, I added this line of code and it showed my saved value.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MarketSegmentID)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Q. Why are you populating the select list in jQuery instead of via a matching `ViewBag.MarketSegmentId` in the controller?

Comment: ...or using a ViewModel?

Comment: @André Figueiredo: He has a ViewModel, do you mean extend it? No need with DropDownLists as they are already wired to look in the ViewBag (see answer below).

Comment: he hasn't said that he has a ViewModel.. What's implicit is that he has the "Model". it can be resolved easily also with strong typed objects.

Comment: Can you explain 'when you open the form back up' is this after a validation error or something? I suspect that you'll need to track the selected value on the server side since you are sending the selected value (in the view model) separate from the list (jquery loading)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a real need to populate the SelectList client side, you are better off putting your SelectList of values straight into a `ViewBag.MarketSegmentId` property in the controller and use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MarketSegmentID)
```

or even just

```
@Html.DropDownList("MarketSegmentID")
```

In the controller you will have something like this (vary to suit your own data):

```
ViewBag.MarketSegmentID = new SelectList(someDataList, "ValueProperty", "NameProperty");
```

`someDataList` can be any collection (e.g. a database table, list etc). The "ValueProperty" is the name of the property in your data that holds the value you want to store (often an int value). The "NameProperty" is the name of the property in your data that holds the text you want to display on each item.

Assuming you want a simple list of integers, generated in sequence, you can add them in a loop like this:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ints.Add(i);
}
ViewBag.MarketSegmentID = new SelectList(ints);
```

If no property names are specified in the `SelectList` constructor it will just use the elements in the collection for both display and values.

MVC will automatically look for a `SelectList` in a `ViewBag` property of the same name as the model property. e.g. `Model.MarketSegmentID` is assumed to be the selected value and `ViewBag.MarketSegmentID` is assumed to hold a matching `SelectList`

It will also populate the current selection from the View Model when the page is displayed, and update your return View Model value from the selection in the list.

*If you describe the type of data, I can update this to show a specific example of populating the SelectList in the controller.*

Comment: @user3036753: You mean it is a simple list of integer values like 0-100 etc?

Comment: Its id's, so it could be 1-10000., data looks like this: Adhesive-1, B&C-2, Coatings-3, etc

Comment: @user3036753: if this is coming from a table, then the first example (specifying the id and display name fields) is your best bet. If you need specific help, you will need to show specific code. I have added more comments in the code sample to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use to do:

Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MarketSegmentID , Model.GetMarketSegmentList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

ViewModel:

```
public int? MarketSegmentID { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> GetMarketSegmentList { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
var vm = new ViewModelWhatever();
[..]
vm.GetMarketSegmentList = GetMarketSegmentList()
                          .ToList()
                          .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                          {
                              Value = x.MarketSegmentID.ToString(),
                              Text = x.Name
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: I was not saying you can't do it this way, I was just saying that MVC provides a simpler way, built-in, by using a ViewBag entry of the same name as the property for the Selectlist. Then you can continue to use a data model instead of introducing an additional ViewModel just to add the SelectList.